# Positivity for mix of convolution and multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, convolution

I am considering an operator of the form $T_\mu = S_\mu^* S_\mu$ with $\mu,k \in \mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, which is a mix of a convolution- and multiplication operator (see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20226/833946) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897951/833946) question),
$$
  S_\mu(f)(x) = (k * (\mu f))(x)
$$
By Fourier transformation, it can be written as
$$
  S_\mu(f)(x) = \int dp ~ e^{ipx} \widetilde k(p) ~ (\mu f)^\sim(p)  = \int dp ~ e^{ipx} \widetilde k(p) (\widetilde \mu * \widetilde f)(p).
$$
This operator is positive as it is of the form $S^* S$ and which can be seen directly
$$
  \langle f, T_\mu f \rangle = \int dp ~ \widetilde{k}^2(p) ~ |(\mu f)^\sim(p)|^2 \geq 0
$$
**Question:** Under what condition on functions $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal C^\infty$ is the difference $T_\mu - T_\nu$ a positive operator?

---

**Attempts:**

- One sufficient condition would be $|(\mu f)^\sim(p)|^2 >  |(\nu f)^\sim(p)|^2$. However, it involves an arbitrary function $f$ and is therefore not easily proven for known $\mu,\nu$.
- For a pure multiplication operator, this requirement would be $|\mu(x)|^2 > |\nu(x)|^2$. For a pure convolution operator, it would be the same condition Fourier transformed. This is a mix of both cases (even though the convolution part is the same). But it is unclear to me how it changes the condition on $\mu,\nu$?
- Maybe $|\mu(x)|^2 > |\nu(x)|^2$ is a sufficient condition, even it is not necessary?

Let me know if more detail is needed. I am thankful for any suggestions!